# Opening pdf in model Dialog in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf

I am opening a page using modelDialog which generate dynamically report and render it on report viewer but I am getting  a blank page when it is render on modelDialog.

```
window.showModelessDialog(strURL, null, "dialogWidth:850px; dialogHeight:1000px;  center:yes;");
```

`strURL` is the url of page which contain Report Viewer to show report but I am getting blank page, I am not getting why it is occure .

Please suggest me any solutions or relates links for solving this problem .

Comment: Are you getting it if you open it as a normal page? I mean are you getting it correct when you do Server.Transfer(strURL) or Response.Redirect(strURL) ?

Comment: Yes , it is properly render report on simple page .